# Get View from custom Preference

Tags: android, android-xml, android-preferences

In my app I have a PreferenceScreen which looks like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="state"
            android:title="@string/stateTitle"
            android:summary="@string/stateSummary"
            android:defaultValue="false" />

    <Preference
            android:key="test"
            android:layout="@layout/pref_control"
            android:dependency="state" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Now my question is how can I get the views which are in my `pref_control.xml` from the PreferenceActivity? I tried with normal `findViewById()` but that ends in a NullPointerException. Here is my code that causes the exception:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.startTime)).setText("bla");
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.endTime)).setText("bla");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Preference by using `Preference p = findPrefences("test")` from the Activity (or better the PreferenceFragment, if you are using newer versions of Android).

On that object you can call `.getView(convertView, parent)`. For your purposes, it should be ok to call that method with null as paramters: `findPreferences("test").getView(null, null)`.

HTH

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using PreferenceActivity, you can use:

```
final CheckBoxPreference stateCheckBox = (CheckBoxPreference)findPreference("state");
```

and presumably:

```
final Preference testPreference = (Preference)findPreference("test");
```

It's deprecated but it should work.

Comment: Yes of course I know that but I use a custom layout in the test preference. In this layout is a button and I want to get this Button but in the `Preference` object I do not have a method called `findViewById()` or something else.

Comment: Oh I see, I guess it is down to when you are using findViewById. I'd have thought that as long as it was after you'd inflated that layout it should be OK.

Comment: I think you should post the code that actually causes the exception

Comment: I updated my question with the code. Do you think I have to inflate the layout for my own again to use the code from above?

Comment: If all you need to do is set the text, just do it in the XML.

Comment: If you need to do more like set listeners I suspect you actually need to Create a ew class extending preference, override its onCreateView method and use findViewById there afetr inflating the XML.

Comment: Okay thank you for that. I have to set dynamic text. I only simplified it here. I will test it with a custom Preference class.